# How to download file with CGI

Tags: c++, cgi, download

I'l like to know what is the code to download a file existing in my C:/ directory using CGI (it may sounds weird, but there is such possibility that the file may exists in a server in another computer's C:/).

I know I have to use Content-Disposition, but all ways I try, my CGI fails to download anything, only creating an empty file with the name an format I gave. Among many ways I tried to make it work, this is the basic code:

```
cout << "Content-type:image/png\r\n";
cout << "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=teste.png\r\n\r\n";
```

For now I'm using an image as data type, but later I'l like to download a specific package of data called .pac.

Thanks for any help,

Momergil

Answer (score 1):

Looks like, you want to upload file not download.

Printing the name of the file in the header is not enouph.
After printing your header, open your file and send its content in raw-bytes mode, and... your done.

You will see a popu pin your client browser asking to save a file.

--

std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;
is better than :
std::cout << "hello world" << "\r\n";

because "\r\n" isn't web standarized, and does'nt work as expected under linux/android.

Comment: ok, I got it. But given that I'm using cout, how can I pass the file path where I want my file to be saved?

Comment: I'm not sure you can do this on server side. This could be a serious security flow in the client. The nice '.pac' could be in fact a virus.

Comment: I think I understand, but I imagine that there is a way how to do it in the CGI script. Besides, always (at least when I try) when the file is loaded, the browser creates a copy in the Downloads folder anyway; so if it were a virus, too late :)

Comment: In firefox the downloads folder is choose by "Firefox->options->General->Download" (firefox 21.0) syntax can vary because I don't use the english client. I thinks it is the nearly the same for every browser.